# Why does not MapHttpAttributeRoutes work in Stateless Web API in service fabric?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, service, owin, azure-service-fabric, stateless

By default, VS 2015 templates for Web API in Service Fabric create a OWIN based hosting for Web API controllers. The default code in Startup.cs file for this service is:

```
public static void ConfigureApp(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    // Configure Web API for self-host. 
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

I replaced this code with following:

```
public static void ConfigureApp(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    // Configure Web API for self-host. 
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

and added

```
[RoutePrefix("mycontroller")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    ...
}
```

and try to navigate it by `http://localhost:port/mycontroller.`

It does not work.

The same code works fine when I create a web api controller with ASP.NET host project.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did you add `Route` attributes to your actions? `RoutePrefix` alone does not create any route.

Comment: You are correct. I forgot to add Route attribute to the action. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute routing works just fine, it's the same ASP.NET whether it's hosted on Service Fabric or somewhere else. We use attribute routing in our [Party Cluster sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-management-party-cluster/tree/master/src/PartyCluster.WebService). As Federico commented, make sure you have more than just the RoutePrefix on your controllers.